# footer floats on top of div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a footer which is floating on top of my div. It works fine on `desktop` view but keeps floating on `mobile` and `tablet` resolutions.

> Problem - the footer is floating over the div on mobile and tablet resolutions.

I know what is the cause of the problem but I am not able to fix the problem. The reason is that there is a floating div above the footer. Because in other pages the footer works just fine. I have added the `css` for it below.

Sample of the page:

```
<div>
    <img />
</div>
<div class="overFlow">
    Floating div over the image. The footer is sitting here
</div>
<footer>
    This floats on mobile view and desktop view.
</footer>


<style>
    .overFlow {
        position: absolute !important;
        top: 50%;
        left: 0%;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what is wrong exactly? Your design has an image, with text over it and a footer which sits on the bottom. I don't see a problem here

Comment: the footer is floating over the div. It is not at the bottom.

Comment: Your `.overflow` floats over the footer because you positioned it absolutely at at center of the screen vertically. If the screen is small, it will go on top of whatever is under it. What were you trying to do?

Comment: Can you please add screen image or more code like what is the CSS for the `.overFlow`

Answer (score 1):

there is a solution to it i.e. remove top:50% from it if it is not important but if you need at 50% only than use media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width:750px)
{
.overflow
{
position:absolute;
top:0%;
}
}
```

so in the desktop it will come properly and in the mobile size below 750 and at 750 it will be top and footer at bottom.

thanks

Comment: This won't solve it, just hide the issue in his current example. If the contents of `.overflow` have more height, same issue will occur.